# How to use function in {{ }} angular

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework

When I try to use function `t('Apple')` in `{{ }}` I got error `_co.t is not a function`

However when I use in `console.log();` it working

My question is **How to use function on `{{ }}`**

`<div>{{ t('Apple') }}</div>`

I import my function from another file (**interface**)

```
import t from '../../translate/interface';
```

this is **interface** file

```
import Translate from './translate';

function t (word: string) {
  return Translate['ar'][word];
}

export default t;
```

Comment: Show your function

Comment: you must have a method with the name t defined on your controller.

Comment: Did you were integrated your controller with html?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The scope of template binding expressions is the components class' instance.
You can't refer to anything outside that scope.

If you want to do that you can use

```
t (word: string) {
  return Translate['fr'][word];
}
```

```
@Component(...)
export MyComp {
 t2 = t; 
}
```

then you can use

```
<div>{{ t2('Apple') }}</div>
```

or better just move it inside the components class

```
@Component(...)
export MyComp {
  t (word: string) {
    return Translate['fr'][word];
  }
}
```

```
<div>{{ t('Apple') }}</div>
```

Or if you want to reuse the code in different components, move the function into an injectable service.

See also https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt4

Answer (score 1):

you shouldn't use a function in to {{}}, if you want translate it, use a pipe or i18n

pipe: https://scotch.io/tutorials/simple-language-translation-in-angular-2-part-1

i18n: https://angular.io/guide/i18n

Answer (score 0):

You should have the function as follows, without the keyword **`function`**

```
 t (word: string) {
  return Translate['fr'][word];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should have an method in you controller (component.ts or ts-file if ionic). The function must return something.

Here is an example:

```
myFunction(value: any): any {
  // do something
  return value;
}
```

and in template:

```
<p>{{ myFunction('Hello World!') }}</p>
```

[Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-nkjvgk) is an working example for ionic. Go to pages->home.ts